# Problems with reading in csv values into 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I am having issues reading in values from a saved csv file. This is part of the csv file that I have:

```
000000216739.jpg, 224, [ 0.  0.  0.  0. 36. 44.  4.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  9. 14. 
8.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  7.  0.  3.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  
0.  0.  0.  0.  3.  1.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  2.  0.  
3.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.], 
[ 0.  0.  0.  0. 35. 33.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  9. 36.  ...]
```

(formatted according to the csv file that I have)

Here's the image of the datafile:
[image]

The problem is, I'm really not sure how to read each comma separate value separately. When I:

```
with open(CSVFilepath) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        print(row[0])
        print(row[1])
        print(row[2])
```

it returns:

```
['000000216739.jpg', '224', '[ 0.  0.  0.  0. 36. 44.  4.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  9. 14.']  
000000216739.jpg  
224   
[ 0.  0.  0.  0. 36. 44.  4.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  9. 14.   ]
```

The value `224` is actually the number of [ ] s (rows) in image `000000216739.jpg`.
What I'm trying to read in is a 2d numpy array of shape (224,60) with the 60 being fixed for all images.

So what I'm trying to read in is:
e.g. for image 123.jpg (everything in one array of shape (224 by 60):

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0. 36. 44.  4.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  9. 14.
  8.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  7.  0.  3.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  3.  1.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  2.  0.
  3.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.],  
...  (more np arrays)...  
[ 6.  0.  0. 35. 64.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 20. 11. 27. 23.  5.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  5.  0. 10.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  6.  2.  3.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  2.  2.  1.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

May I ask what I should do..? Also, this file is quite large and I need a way to read it efficiently... Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I presume your data is like this; filename,nrows,[imrow1],[imrow2],[imrow3], ...,[imrow_nrows] then do the following to extract the image from your data. Let us know if your data is formatted differently.

```
with open(CSVFilepath) as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')

  for row in reader:
    fname=row[0]
    nrows=int(row[1])
    imdata=np.array(row[2:]) #Get from the 2 element to the end. Could also do row[:-nrows]
  #might need to make each element an int or float.        
  ###reshape if that's what you need and do something with the image
```

Comment: Hello @The Puternerd, thanks alot for helping. But it gives this error: line 27, in <module>
    nrows=int(row[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I created a file called testdata.csv with this line in it 000000216739.jpg,224,[ 0. 0. 0. 0. 36. 44. 4. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 9. 14.8. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7. 0. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 1. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 2. 0.3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.],[ 0. 0. 0. 0. 35. 33. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 9. 36.]

Comment: `import csv
 import numpy as np

 with open('testdata.csv') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')

  for row in reader:
    fname=row[0]
    nrows=int(row[1])
    imdata=np.array(row[2:])`

With this code it work as expected. Is the data as I have assumed?

Comment: It seems like it is the same...I've added the image (screenshot) of the csv file as well...not sure if its the same..?

Comment: In your example code you reference row[1] so if you remove int from the line does it change anything? The error says to me that row[1] doesnt exist- yet you have used it yourself.

Comment: Oh no...it seems like the list index out of range error is still there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181860/discussion-between-reine-fang-and-the-puternerd).

Comment: so if you print(row[1]) like in your code you will also get an out of index error. Maybe your data isn't formatted as you think - maybe the first line is empty with no rows? But given your example this code is not really much different.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not a correct csv file, and you should not read it like a csv file.

The linebreak in csv file represent a new row whereas it's apparent that in your file they don't mean that - you want to read the numbers inside `[` and `]` but they're not delimited properly.

A way to dissect this file would be to

```
with open(file,'r') as fin:
    f = fin.readlines()
    f = ' '.join(f) # remove newlines
    listrows = f.split('[')
    listrows = [l.split(']')[0] for l in listrows] # Get string between '[' and ']'
    matrix = [row.split('.') for row in listrows] # This is now a 2D matrix
    final = [[int(e.replace(' ','')) for e in row] for row in matrix] # Here goes your final matrix
```

I used list comprehension extensively so this does not go to 30 lines. Try running this.

Comment: Hi @Rocky Li, thanks so much for helping. May I ask what do you mean by strip -> int()..?

Comment: Because I tried this:  for row2 in matrix:
          output = [ a for a in row2 if a.isnumeric() ]
          print( output ) but it returned me empty lists...

Comment: @ReineFang that won't work because you'll be looking at `' 10'`, etc, these are strings, so a.isnumeric will return false. by strip I mean you can strip the whitespace off each of these with `a.replace(' ','')` and then convert it using `int(a)`.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but would you mind updating your code above? I'm abit confused...

Comment: @ReineFang I tried, if it still doesn't work maybe you want to send me the full file?

Comment: That'll be really great, but may I ask how I can send you..?

Comment: @ReineFang do you have a github link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181917/discussion-between-reine-fang-and-rocky-li).