# problems with reading and writing np array from and to csv file

Tags: python, csv, numpy

This is a (different) continuation from a question I [previously posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52809454/problems-with-reading-in-csv-values-into-2d-numpy-array).
My previous csv file was badly formatted and @The Puternerd kindly suggested that I flatten my 2d array before writing it to file.

So here's what I have:

```
output = open(CSVFilepath,"w")

csvwriter=csv.writer(output, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

for imagePath in glob.glob(MaskImagePath):
...
    #myDescriptor is the 2d np array with varying rows and fixed columns (60)
    myrow=[imageID,myDescriptor.shape[0],myDescriptor.flatten()]
```

Here's what my csv file looks like now:

```
000000216739.jpg,224,[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 1. 2.]
000000001268.jpg,173,[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 1. 0.]
000000166259.jpg,195,[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 2.]
000000368900.jpg,226,[0. 0. 0. ... 1. 1. 1.]
```

But when I tried to retrieve the third item with:

```
with open(CSVFilepath,'r') as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fin,delimiter=',')

        for row in reader:
            print(row[2])
            print(type(row[2]))
            print(np.array(list(row[2])))
```

it returns:

```
[0. 0. 0. ... 1. 3. 2.]
<class 'str'>
['[' '0' '.' ' ' '0' '.' ' ' '0' '.' ' ' '.' '.' '.' ' ' '1' '.' ' ' '3' '.' ' ' '2' '.' ']']
```

Does this mean that I didn't save the values properly? Any advice would be really appreciated!!!

**********Update**************

Reading @Navneeth instructions below, right now I have this code:

```
with open(CSVFilepath,'r') as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fin,delimiter=',')

        for row in reader:
            print(row[2])
            print(type(row[2]))
            a = row[2].replace("\n","")
            print(a)
            print(np.fromstring(a[1:-1], dtype=float, sep=" "))
```

but it prints:

```
[0. 0. 0. ... 1. 2. 0.]
<class 'str'>
[0. 0. 0. ... 1. 2. 0.]
[0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. ... 1. 3. 2.]
<class 'str'>
[0. 0. 0. ... 1. 3. 2.]
[0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
<class 'str'>
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0.]
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an issue with the encoding to the CSV file per se. However, the `CSVReader` has no way of recognizing that you're trying to read a numpy array from the third column, so it simply returns the string representation of that numpy array.

The reason that your third print statement gives you that odd formatting is that using `numpy.array` on a string will cause numpy to interpret it as an array of individual characters (which is natural, since this function will decompose any iterable into its individual elements, same as if you call `list("mystring")`).

Here's one short way of interpreting the string as a numpy array using `numpy.fromstring`.

```
def string_to_numpy(column):
  return numpy.fromstring(column[1:-1], dtype=float, sep=" ")
```

The splice is necessary because `numpy.fromstring` doesn't expect the `[` and `]` characters in an input. The call uses a single space character as the separator, though you could be fancier and use regular expressions if this wasn't general enough.

Note that the array produced here is flat. If you want to restore the dimensionality of the array, you'll have to use `numpy.array.reshape` after extracting the dimensions as integers.

Comment: When i tried to do this:                                                                                        
                          for row in reader:
    print(np.fromstring(row[2][1:-1], dtype=float, sep=" ")) it returns just this: [0. 0. 0.] (the first part before the ellipses)
Am I misinterpreting your instructions?

Comment: The ellipses should not be there. I assumed you left them as a placeholder. One way of turning a numpy array to a string seems to be `str(myarray).replace("\n","")`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand your instructions...I'll update with codes so its clearer maybe..?

Comment: I'm saying the CSV file should not have the ellipses in the first place. You're not encoding the numpy array properly in the CSV.

Comment: oh... i thought you said that there's no issue with the encoding to the csv file but since its like that may i ask how should i encode it instead?